# Street View issues using a URL with lat long parameters

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

I've been scratching my head since last week over this. When we attempt to open a new Street View tab from our site, we rarely get correct results. Here's the URL we use:

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=45.323278375882055,-72.65983604558379&cbp=11,-204.04381419981723,0,0,0

Sometimes we'll be in front of the correct house, but most times we'll be 2-3 houses over. Even if we test with a lat,long provided by google maps itself (by entering the house address), we'll get the incorrect result. I know there are panoramas that exist for those other houses, but it's as if when using the StreetView URL only some points are considered (e.g. every 20-30m) when calculating the closest panorama for this lat long.

To convince myself of this, I did this simple test: I enter this address in Google Maps: "345 artisans, bromont, quebec"
We can see the lat long for this address in the URL generated by Google: 45.3232061,-72.6597534
If we click on the StreetView link directly in Google Maps, it brings us in front of the correct house, but if we attempt to use the lat long from this, in our Street View URL:
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=45.3233769,-72.6599646&cbp=11,-204.04381419981723,0,0,0

Wrong panorama. Even though I passed the exact lat long for the panorama of the correct house.

Is this a bug, limitation, or am I doing something wrong?

To work around this, I thought about using the Google Maps API (without a key) to first get the panorama id for the address first and directly use this id in the Street View URL (instead of a lat long), but I fear even this little use of the API goes against the TOS for commercial web sites.

Thanks for any help or confirmation you can provide

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a bug. [image]

I tried the perimeters with the [Google Street View Image API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro) and I am stull getting the same result.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x600&location=45.3233075,-72.6601952&heading=180&key=key
```

You might want to consider filing a bug for it.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the confirmation. We're currently looking into using the API to get the panorama id first, and use that instead of the lat long. Because using the lat long URL doesn't work on mobile anyway. On mobile the lat long in the URL is ignored and it tries to use your location instead. It seems only the panorama id will work on mobile.